# Sort data based on time-steps?

Tags: r, dataframe

Can somebody help me with this, I need to sort the timings of my data set in increasing order. How can I do this?

```
Input:
 
11:00 02:40 05:50 03:20
 1     1     1     1
 0     1     1     1
 0     1     1     1

Output:

 02:40  03:20  05:50  11:00
    1    1     1       1
    1    1     1       0
    1    1     1       0


Sample data:

  
 df<-structure(list(c("11:00", 1, 0, 0),
                       c("02:40", 1, 1, 1), c("05:50", 1, 1, 1), c("03:20",  1,  1,1)), row.names = c(NA,4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `chron` and `order`

```
df[order(chron::times(paste0(df[1,], ":00")))]
#1 02:40 03:20 05:50 11:00
#2     1     1     1     1
#3     1     1     1     0
#4     1     1     1     0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `order` on `as.difftime` of row 1.

```
df[,order(as.difftime(as.character(df[1,]), "%H:%M"))]
#1 02:40 03:20 05:50 11:00
#2     1     1     1     1
#3     1     1     1     0
#4     1     1     1     0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `order` + `strptime`

```
> df[order(strptime(df[1,],"%H:%M"))]

1 02:40 03:20 05:50 11:00
2     1     1     1     1
3     1     1     1     0
4     1     1     1     0
```